# JSON data is not updated when i removing the dynamic row value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I implemented dynamic add and remove functionality in my project.

Add functionality working fine but when I am deleting the data based on the checkbox selection and trying to remove the dynamic row then Json is not updating.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in Measurelist">
                            <td><input type="checkbox"
                                ng-model="personalDetail.selected" value="[$index]"/></td>
                            <td width="300">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group"
                                        ng-class="{'has-error':!theForm.measureCode.$valid && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted),
                                        'has-success':theForm.measureCode.$valid && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted)}">

                                        <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in a"
                                            ng-model="formModel.AbcMeasure.measureCode[$index]"
                                            name="measureCode" required="required"
                                            ng-change="setRequired()">
                                            <option value="">-- Select Code --</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td width="300">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group"
                                        ng-class="{'has-error':!theForm.measureType.$valid && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted),
                                        'has-success':theForm.measureType.$valid && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted)}">

                                        <select class="form-control"
                                            ng-options="item for item in b[formModel.abcMeasure.measureCode[$index]]"
                                            ng-model="formModel.abcMeasure.measureType[$index]"
                                            name="measureType" required="required">
                                            <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><textarea  class="form-control" ng-maxlength="1000" 
                                    ng-model="formModel.abcMeasure.measureDescription[$index]"
                                    name="measureDescription" id="textArea"
                                    ng-required="textRequired[$index]"></textarea></td>
                                    <td><input type="button" ng-click="remove()" value="Remove" /></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

js file

```
$scope.formModel = {
                                internationalClient : 0,
                                isConfidential : 0,
                                isModificationLossRecog : 0,
                                idenComplianceForFinDifficulty : 1,
                                idenComplianceForConcession : 1,
                                idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin : 1,
                                abcMeasure : {
                                    
                                    measureDescription : {

                                    }
                                }
                            };


$scope.abcMeasurelist = [ {} ];

                            $scope.addNew = function(personalDetail) {

                                $scope.abcMeasurelist
                                        .push({
                                            /*
                                             * 'mCode' : "", 'mType' : "",
                                             * 'comments' : "",
                                             */

                                            'measureCode' : $scope.formModel.abcMeasure.measureCode,
                                            'measureType' : $scope.formModel.abcMeasure.measureType,
                                            'measureDescription' : $scope.formModel.abcMeasure.measureDescription,
                                        });
                                console.log("$scope.abcMeasurelist:: "+ angular.toJson(
                                        $scope.abcMeasurelist, false));
                            };

                            $scope.remove = function() {
                                var newDataList = [];
                                $scope.selectedAll = false;
                                var data1;
                                
                                angular
                                        .forEach(
                                                $scope.abcMeasurelist,
                                                function(selected) {
                                                    if (!selected.selected) {
                                                        console
                                                                .log("selected :: "
                                                                        + selected);
                                                        newDataList
                                                                .push(selected);
                                                                                                            
                                                    }
                                                });
                                
                                $scope.abcMeasurelist = newDataList;
                            };
```

So I need below output.

If my JSON is like.

```
    {"internationalClient":0,"isConfidential":0,"isModificationLossRecog":0,"idenComplianceForFinDifficulty":1,"idenComplianceForConcession":1,"idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin":1,
"abcMeasure":[
{"measureCode":"A-Reduction of the interest payable",
"measureType":"Permanent",
"measureDescription":"gfdgdf"},
{
"measureCode":"C-Reduction of the repayment amounts",
"measureType":"Temporary",
"measureDescription":"ghgfdh"
},
{
"measureCode":"D-Rescheduling repayment amounts",
"measureType":"Temporary",
"measureDescription":"hgfhgf"
}
]}
```

If I want to delete C one or two dynamic rows from the GUI, then my json will remove abcMeasure -->measureDescription -->measureCode-->measureType index value based on the selection from GUI.

```
{
{"internationalClient":0,"isConfidential":0,"isModificationLossRecog":0,"idenComplianceForFinDifficulty":1,"idenComplianceForConcession":1,"idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin":1,
"abcMeasure":[
{"measureCode":"A-Reduction of the interest payable",
"measureType":"Permanent",
"measureDescription":"gfdgdf"},
{
"measureCode":"D-Rescheduling repayment amounts",
"measureType":"Temporary",
"measureDescription":"hgfhgf"
}
]}
```

Please provide me solution on this.

Comment: Can you please format your code properly so it is more readable.

Comment: Formated, please help on this.

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?